# Convert a dataframe into a column sum of two of its columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I was wondering how to convert my `Data` below to my `Desired_output`?

My `Desired_output` is a columsum of `n_started` and  `n_finished` columns for each `district` in `Data`.

```
Data = read.table(h=TRUE,text="
district grade n_started  n_finished
A        1     5          9
A        2     3          6
B        1     1          2
B        2     2          4
B        3     6          7")

Desired_output=
"
district  n_started  n_finished
A         5+3          9+6
B        1+2+6        2+4+7"
```

Comment: Base R: `aggregate(n_started + n_finished ~ district, Data, FUN = sum)`. Dplyr: `group_by(Data, district) %>% summarize(across(c(n_started, n_finished), ~ sum(.)))`. Data.table: `as.data.table(Data)[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("n_started", "n_finished"), by = .(district)]`.

Comment: SimonHarmel, if the dupe-links (and my previous comment) don't work for you, [edit] your question to expand the example so that it reflects why the given solutions don't work, then @-ping me and we'll discuss and optionally reopen. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tidyverse group_by and summarise to accomplish this:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data %>% 
  group_by(district) %>%
  summarise(n_started = sum(n_started), n_finished = sum(n_finished))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate()`

```
Desired_output = aggregate(cbind(n_started=Data$n_started, n_finished=Data$n_finished), by=list(district=Data$district), FUN=sum)
```